# HTML/CSS/JS - adding an image to input[type=submit]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an ecommerce store and have a payment gateway where I need to use `input[type=submit]`

It cannot be a `button` or `input[type=image]` but I want to put an icon in the value.

I need text and an icon something like `submit >>` except the '>' is a `PNG`.

I've been looking for a while and don't think this is possible. Is there any workarounds to get what I'm looking for.

I was thinking of creating an image and using `css` to add a bg image but this won't be as responsive for different devices etc,.

Any ideas or suggestions for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply create whatever you want (a `<p>` containing an `<img>` or example) and listen to the `click` event on it. Submit your form then.

Comment: @Zenoo I can't unfortunately. For my payment gateway to work it has to be input[type=submit]. I had <button onclick="this.form.submit"> but this will not work.

Comment: `input[type=image]` behaves differently in what data it actually sends (image click coordinates), but between a normal `input[type=submit]` and a submit `button`, there should be no significant differences. _“I had <button onclick="this.form.submit"> but this will not work”_ - well then maybe it is not what you need to begin with; but we can’t know what that is, if you don’t show us how this form normally gets submitted to begin with. Show us the original, “working” input field, plus any JS logic that might be attached to it.

Comment: @misorude input[type=submit] is the only thing that will work for my payment gateway no js or anything, I tried changing it to a button for styling purposes only.

Comment: Show us the HTML for the original submit `input`. As long as you specify name and value the same for a submit `button`, I don’t see why this should not work.

Comment: @misorude `<input type="submit" value="Complete your Order" id="pay_now_button">` its a basic submit input. And it has to be this way for my payment gateway not submitted via JS. Thats just the way my payment gateway works. The only reason to try anything different was purely asthetic.

Comment: That doesn’t even have a `name` attribute, so it does not cause a name=value pair in the form submission data set. So submitting the form in a different way - for example by triggering the submit method of the form via JavaScript - should work with the same results. _“And it has to be this way for my payment gateway not submitted via JS.”_ - that doesn’t make much sense, the payment gateway has no way of knowing _how_ your form was submitted to begin with.

Comment: @misorude The payment gateway hijacks the form submission behavior to inject a payment method nonce in the submission. By submitting as soon as the button is clicked, you are skipping the Drop-In behavior and not receiving a payment method nonce. https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/javascript/v2#form

Comment: Well that is important information that should have been part of your question to begin with … If this script specifically tries to select a/the `input type=submit` element inside the given form, then of course this can’t work with any other type of element. (Unless you want to go for tricks like hiding the original, and then triggering a click event on it when your own button gets clicked.)

Comment: @misorude This was part of my original question 'have a payment gateway where I need to use input[type=submit]'

Comment: Yes, but there was no way of telling whether that was an actual technical requirement, or if you simply didn’t manage to get it working ;-) You should have linked to the documentation explaining what is actually going on to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with css by doing the following code. Don't use inline this will make your input tag messy.

```css
.YourInputClass
{ 
    background-image:url('http://portal.3spos.com/content/images/flag-saudi-arabia.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
    padding-left:14px;
}
```

```html
   <input class="YourInputClass" style="text-align: right;"  type="textbox" name="text"/>
```

Comment: Thanks this works exactly as I wanted. However I want to apply this to a few buttons with different text in them and was hoping to try get the text and the icon centered together. At the moment the text is centered and the image has x+y co-ordinates in background-position.

Comment: You are welcome you can change the styling as you want. Good Luck